# Do we need to have different virtualenv for different project in django

Tags: django

I have installed django and have set up virtualenv with the name let be 'xyz' and working on project A. Can I work on project B using that 'xyz' virtualenv or should I go for another virtualenv suppose to be 'pqr'?

Comment: Not per se, but why not. It makes it more convenient, especially since you can isolete the two projects, and upgrade the two indepdently. Furthermore a virtual environment does not take that much disk space.

Comment: If the question is "can you" the answer is yes. If the question is "should you", then I would  say that depends. It might be wise to have a separate environment for projects meant for production, but I start a lot of projects I never plan to finish (tutorials or practice or whatever), and just start whatever environment that has django or whatever I need

Comment: Thank you so much all of you for your right guidance and your valuable answers. It will help me a lot. Thank you.